# wpa_supplicant: connect to mobile tethering but not to the router

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, wireless-router, gentoo, wpa-supplicant

Also my phone works successfully as a client of this Wi-Fi router, and even now I tether from this phone that is a client of this Wi-Fi.

Wired connection (ethernet) from the same laptop to this router also works.

Boot from Xubuntu: Wi-Fi works. Maybe something is missing in [my kernel](https://gitlab.com/vitaly-zdanevich-configs/linux-kernel-thinkpad-t430/-/blob/x64/.config)?

My `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
ctrl_interface_group=0
update_config=1


network={
    ssid="271"
    psk="this not connect :("
    mesh_fwding=1
}
network={
    ssid="POCO X3 Pro"
    psk="this is my phone, works"
    priority=2
    mesh_fwding=1
}

...other networks here
```

`lspci -k`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller
    Kernel driver in use: ivb_uncore
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i915
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo ThinkPad T430
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville)
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo QM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family Thermal Management Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family Thermal Management Controller
02:00.0 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd PCIe SDXC/MMC Host Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo PCIe SDXC/MMC Host Controller
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] (rev 34)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 (802.11a/b/g/n)
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

`emerge --info`:

```
Portage 3.0.30 (python 3.9.9-final-0, default/linux/amd64/17.1/no-multilib, gcc-11.2.1, glibc-2.34-r10, 5.15.26-gentoo+ x86_64)
=================================================================
System uname: Linux-5.15.26-gentoo+-x86_64-Intel-R-_Core-TM-_i7-3840QM_CPU_@_2.80GHz-with-glibc2.34
KiB Mem:    16098584 total,  11190072 free
KiB Swap:   15625212 total,  15625212 free
Timestamp of repository gentoo: Sun, 10 Apr 2022 00:45:01 +0000
Head commit of repository gentoo: 987e04f9402b079fc36ef7d928202b6943241b33
sh bash 5.1_p16
ld GNU ld (Gentoo 2.37_p1 p2) 2.37
app-misc/pax-utils:        1.3.3::gentoo
app-shells/bash:           5.1_p16::gentoo
dev-lang/perl:             5.34.0-r6::gentoo
dev-lang/python:           3.9.9-r1::gentoo, 3.10.2_p1::gentoo
dev-lang/rust:             1.58.1::gentoo
dev-util/cmake:            3.22.2::gentoo
dev-util/meson:            0.60.3::gentoo
sys-apps/baselayout:       2.7-r3::gentoo
sys-apps/openrc:           0.44.10::gentoo
sys-apps/sandbox:          2.29::gentoo
sys-devel/autoconf:        2.13-r1::gentoo, 2.71-r1::gentoo
sys-devel/automake:        1.16.5::gentoo
sys-devel/binutils:        2.37_p1-r2::gentoo
sys-devel/binutils-config: 5.4.1::gentoo
sys-devel/clang:           13.0.1::gentoo
sys-devel/gcc:             11.2.1_p20220115::gentoo
sys-devel/gcc-config:      2.5-r1::gentoo
sys-devel/libtool:         2.4.6-r6::gentoo
sys-devel/llvm:            13.0.1::gentoo
sys-devel/make:            4.3::gentoo
sys-kernel/linux-headers:  5.15-r3::gentoo (virtual/os-headers)
sys-libs/glibc:            2.34-r10::gentoo
Repositories:

gentoo
    location: /var/db/repos/gentoo
    sync-type: rsync
    sync-uri: rsync://rsync2.ru.gentoo.org/gentoo-portage/
    priority: -1000
    sync-rsync-verify-max-age: 24
    sync-rsync-verify-jobs: 1
    sync-rsync-verify-metamanifest: yes
    sync-rsync-extra-opts: 

ACCEPT_KEYWORDS="amd64"
ACCEPT_LICENSE="@FREE @FREE ipw3945"
CBUILD="x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
CFLAGS="-O2 -march=native -pipe"
CHOST="x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
CONFIG_PROTECT="/etc /usr/share/gnupg/qualified.txt"
CONFIG_PROTECT_MASK="/etc/ca-certificates.conf /etc/dconf /etc/env.d /etc/fonts/fonts.conf /etc/gconf /etc/gentoo-release /etc/revdep-rebuild /etc/sandbox.d /etc/terminfo"
CXXFLAGS="-O2 -march=native -pipe"
DISTDIR="/var/cache/distfiles"
ENV_UNSET="CARGO_HOME DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS DISPLAY GOBIN GOPATH PERL5LIB PERL5OPT PERLPREFIX PERL_CORE PERL_MB_OPT PERL_MM_OPT XAUTHORITY XDG_CACHE_HOME XDG_CONFIG_HOME XDG_DATA_HOME XDG_RUNTIME_DIR"
FCFLAGS="-O2 -march=native -pipe"
FEATURES="assume-digests binpkg-docompress binpkg-dostrip binpkg-logs buildpkg-live config-protect-if-modified distlocks ebuild-locks fixlafiles ipc-sandbox merge-sync multilib-strict network-sandbox news parallel-fetch pid-sandbox preserve-libs protect-owned qa-unresolved-soname-deps sandbox sfperms strict unknown-features-warn unmerge-logs unmerge-orphans userfetch userpriv usersandbox usersync xattr"
FFLAGS="-O2 -march=native -pipe"
GENTOO_MIRRORS="https://ftp.linux.org.tr/gentoo/ http://ftp.byfly.by/pub/gentoo-distfiles/ http://mirror.yandex.ru/gentoo-distfiles/"
LANG="C.UTF8"
LDFLAGS="-Wl,-O1 -Wl,--as-needed"
PKGDIR="/var/cache/binpkgs"
PORTAGE_CONFIGROOT="/"
PORTAGE_RSYNC_OPTS="--recursive --links --safe-links --perms --times --omit-dir-times --compress --force --whole-file --delete --stats --human-readable --timeout=180 --exclude=/distfiles --exclude=/local --exclude=/packages --exclude=/.git"
PORTAGE_TMPDIR="/var/tmp"
RUSTFLAGS="-C target-cpu=native"
SHELL="/bin/bash"
USE="X acl amd64 bzip2 cli crypt dbus dri egl elogind eme-free ffmpeg flac fortran gdbm iconv jpeg libglvnd libtirpc lto mp3 ncurses nls nptl ogg opengl openmp opus pam pcre pgo png pulseaudio readline seccomp split-usr ssl svg tiff unicode v4l vaapi vpx webp xattr xml zlib" ABI_X86="64" ADA_TARGET="gnat_2020" APACHE2_MODULES="authn_core authz_core socache_shmcb unixd actions alias auth_basic authn_alias authn_anon authn_dbm authn_default authn_file authz_dbm authz_default authz_groupfile authz_host authz_owner authz_user autoindex cache cgi cgid dav dav_fs dav_lock deflate dir disk_cache env expires ext_filter file_cache filter headers include info log_config logio mem_cache mime mime_magic negotiation rewrite setenvif speling status unique_id userdir usertrack vhost_alias" CALLIGRA_FEATURES="karbon sheets words" COLLECTD_PLUGINS="df interface irq load memory rrdtool swap syslog" CPU_FLAGS_X86="aes avx f16c mmx mmxext pclmul popcnt rdrand sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3" ELIBC="glibc" GPSD_PROTOCOLS="ashtech aivdm earthmate evermore fv18 garmin garmintxt gpsclock greis isync itrax mtk3301 nmea ntrip navcom oceanserver oldstyle oncore rtcm104v2 rtcm104v3 sirf skytraq superstar2 timing tsip tripmate tnt ublox ubx" GRUB_PLATFORMS="pc" INPUT_DEVICES="libinput" KERNEL="linux" LCD_DEVICES="bayrad cfontz cfontz633 glk hd44780 lb216 lcdm001 mtxorb ncurses text" LIBREOFFICE_EXTENSIONS="presenter-console presenter-minimizer" LLVM_TARGETS="x64" LUA_SINGLE_TARGET="lua5-1" LUA_TARGETS="lua5-1" OFFICE_IMPLEMENTATION="libreoffice" PHP_TARGETS="php7-4 php8-0" POSTGRES_TARGETS="postgres12 postgres13" PYTHON_SINGLE_TARGET="python3_9" PYTHON_TARGETS="python3_9" RUBY_TARGETS="ruby26 ruby27" USERLAND="GNU" VIDEO_CARDS="intel i965" XTABLES_ADDONS="quota2 psd pknock lscan length2 ipv4options ipset ipp2p iface geoip fuzzy condition tee tarpit sysrq proto steal rawnat logmark ipmark dhcpmac delude chaos account"
Unset:  ADDR2LINE, AR, ARFLAGS, AS, ASFLAGS, CC, CCLD, CONFIG_SHELL, CPP, CPPFLAGS, CTARGET, CXX, CXXFILT, ELFEDIT, EMERGE_DEFAULT_OPTS, EXTRA_ECONF, F77FLAGS, FC, GCOV, GPROF, INSTALL_MASK, LC_ALL, LD, LEX, LFLAGS, LIBTOOL, LINGUAS, MAKE, MAKEFLAGS, MAKEOPTS, NM, OBJCOPY, OBJDUMP, PORTAGE_BINHOST, PORTAGE_BUNZIP2_COMMAND, PORTAGE_COMPRESS, PORTAGE_COMPRESS_FLAGS, PORTAGE_RSYNC_EXTRA_OPTS, RANLIB, READELF, SIZE, STRINGS, STRIP, YACC, YFLAGS
```

`/etc/init.d/wpa_supplicant -d -d -d start`:

```
+ sourcex -e /etc/rc.conf
+ '[' -e = -e ']'
+ shift
+ '[' -e /etc/rc.conf ']'
+ . /etc/rc.conf
++ rc_shell=/sbin/sulogin
++ unicode=YES
++ rc_tty_number=12
+ '[' -d /etc/rc.conf.d ']'
+ _conf_d=/etc/init.d/../conf.d
+ _c=wpa_supplicant
+ '[' -n wpa_supplicant -a wpa_supplicant '!=' wpa_supplicant ']'
+ unset _c
+ sourcex -e /etc/init.d/../conf.d/wpa_supplicant.default
+ '[' -e = -e ']'
+ shift
+ '[' -e /etc/init.d/../conf.d/wpa_supplicant.default ']'
+ return 1
+ sourcex -e /etc/init.d/../conf.d/wpa_supplicant
+ '[' -e = -e ']'
+ shift
+ '[' -e /etc/init.d/../conf.d/wpa_supplicant ']'
+ . /etc/init.d/../conf.d/wpa_supplicant
++ wpa_supplicant_args=
+ unset _conf_d
+ sourcex /lib/rc/sh/runit.sh
+ '[' /lib/rc/sh/runit.sh = -e ']'
+ . /lib/rc/sh/runit.sh
+ sourcex /lib/rc/sh/s6.sh
+ '[' /lib/rc/sh/s6.sh = -e ']'
+ . /lib/rc/sh/s6.sh
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ s6_service_path=/var/svc.d/wpa_supplicant
+ sourcex /lib/rc/sh/start-stop-daemon.sh
+ '[' /lib/rc/sh/start-stop-daemon.sh = -e ']'
+ . /lib/rc/sh/start-stop-daemon.sh
+ sourcex /lib/rc/sh/supervise-daemon.sh
+ '[' /lib/rc/sh/supervise-daemon.sh = -e ']'
+ . /lib/rc/sh/supervise-daemon.sh
++ extra_commands='healthcheck unhealthy '
+ sourcex /etc/init.d/wpa_supplicant
+ '[' /etc/init.d/wpa_supplicant = -e ']'
+ . /etc/init.d/wpa_supplicant
++ command=/usr/sbin/wpa_supplicant
++ : /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
++ wpa_supplicant_if=
++ command_args=' -B -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf '
++ name='WPA Supplicant Daemon'
+ yesno ''
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ return 1
+ for _cmd in "$@"
+ '[' start '!=' status -a start '!=' describe ']'
+ '[' -n '' ']'
++ command -v cgroup_add_service
+ '[' cgroup_add_service = cgroup_add_service ']'
+ grep -qs /sys/fs/cgroup /proc/1/mountinfo
+ '[' -d /sys/fs/cgroup -a '!' -w /sys/fs/cgroup ']'
+ cgroup_add_service
+ for d in /sys/fs/cgroup/*
+ '[' -w /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio/tasks ']'
+ printf %d 0
+ for d in /sys/fs/cgroup/*
+ '[' -w /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/tasks ']'
+ printf %d 0
+ for d in /sys/fs/cgroup/*
+ '[' -w /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct/tasks ']'
+ printf %d 0
+ for d in /sys/fs/cgroup/*
+ '[' -w /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/tasks ']'
+ printf %d 0
+ for d in /sys/fs/cgroup/*
+ '[' -w /sys/fs/cgroup/devices/tasks ']'
+ printf %d 0
+ for d in /sys/fs/cgroup/*
+ '[' -w /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer/tasks ']'
+ printf %d 0
+ for d in /sys/fs/cgroup/*
+ '[' -w /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb/tasks ']'
+ printf %d 0
+ for d in /sys/fs/cgroup/*
+ '[' -w /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/tasks ']'
+ printf %d 0
+ for d in /sys/fs/cgroup/*
+ '[' -w /sys/fs/cgroup/net_prio/tasks ']'
+ printf %d 0
+ for d in /sys/fs/cgroup/*
+ '[' -w /sys/fs/cgroup/openrc/tasks ']'
+ printf %d 0
+ for d in /sys/fs/cgroup/*
+ '[' -w /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event/tasks ']'
+ printf %d 0
+ for d in /sys/fs/cgroup/*
+ '[' -w /sys/fs/cgroup/pids/tasks ']'
+ printf %d 0
+ for d in /sys/fs/cgroup/*
+ '[' -w /sys/fs/cgroup/unified/tasks ']'
+ openrc_cgroup=/sys/fs/cgroup/openrc
+ '[' -d /sys/fs/cgroup/openrc ']'
+ cgroup=/sys/fs/cgroup/openrc/wpa_supplicant
+ mkdir -p /sys/fs/cgroup/openrc/wpa_supplicant
+ '[' -w /sys/fs/cgroup/openrc/wpa_supplicant/tasks ']'
+ printf %d 0
++ command -v cgroup_set_limits
+ '[' cgroup_set_limits = cgroup_set_limits ']'
+ cgroup_set_limits
+ local blkio=
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ local cpu=
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ local cpuacct=
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ local cpuset=
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ local devices=
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ local hugetlb=
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ local memory=
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ local net_cls=
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ local net_prio=
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ local pids=
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ return 0
++ command -v cgroup2_set_limits
+ '[' cgroup2_set_limits = cgroup2_set_limits ']'
+ '[' start = start ']'
+ cgroup2_set_limits
+ local cgroup_path
++ cgroup2_find_path
++ grep -qw cgroup2 /proc/filesystems
++ case "${rc_cgroup_mode:-hybrid}" in
++ printf /sys/fs/cgroup/unified
++ return 0
+ cgroup_path=/sys/fs/cgroup/unified
+ '[' -z /sys/fs/cgroup/unified ']'
+ mountinfo -q /sys/fs/cgroup/unified
+ rc_cgroup_path=/sys/fs/cgroup/unified/wpa_supplicant
+ '[' '!' -d /sys/fs/cgroup/unified/wpa_supplicant ']'
+ mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/unified/wpa_supplicant
+ '[' -f /sys/fs/cgroup/unified/wpa_supplicant/cgroup.procs ']'
+ printf 0
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ return 0
+ break
+ eval 'printf '\''%s\n'\'' '
++ printf '%s\n'
+ read _d
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ read _d
+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
+ unset _d
+ eval 'printf '\''%s\n'\'' '
++ printf '%s\n'
+ read _f
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ read _f
+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
+ unset _f
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ '[' -n start ']'
+ '[' start = depend ']'
+ for _cmd in describe start stop status ${extra_commands:-$opts} $extra_started_commands $extra_stopped_commands
+ '[' describe = start ']'
+ for _cmd in describe start stop status ${extra_commands:-$opts} $extra_started_commands $extra_stopped_commands
+ '[' start = start ']'
++ command -v start
+ '[' start = start ']'
+ yesno
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ return 1
+ for _cmd in $extra_stopped_commands
+ '[' cgroup_cleanup = start ']'
+ unset _cmd
+ case $1 in
+ verify_boot
+ '[' '!' -e /run/openrc/softlevel ']'
+ return 0
++ command -v start_pre
+ '[' start_pre = start_pre ']'
+ start_pre
+ case " $command_args" in
+ append_wireless
+ local iface= i=
++ find_wireless
++ local iface=
++ case "$RC_UNAME" in
++ for iface in /sys/class/net/*
++ '[' -e /sys/class/net/enp0s25/wireless -o -e /sys/class/net/enp0s25/phy80211 ']'
++ for iface in /sys/class/net/*
++ '[' -e /sys/class/net/lo/wireless -o -e /sys/class/net/lo/phy80211 ']'
++ for iface in /sys/class/net/*
++ '[' -e /sys/class/net/wlp3s0/wireless -o -e /sys/class/net/wlp3s0/phy80211 ']'
++ echo wlp3s0
++ return 0
+ iface=wlp3s0
+ '[' -n wlp3s0 ']'
+ for i in $iface
+ command_args=' -B -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf  -iwlp3s0'
+ start
+ default_start
+ local func=ssd_start
+ case "$supervisor" in
+ ssd_start
+ '[' -z /usr/sbin/wpa_supplicant ']'
+ local _background=
+ ebegin 'Starting WPA Supplicant Daemon'
 * Starting WPA Supplicant Daemon ...
+ yesno ''
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ return 1
+ yesno ''
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ return 1
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ eval start-stop-daemon --start --exec /usr/sbin/wpa_supplicant -- -B -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlp3s0
++ start-stop-daemon --start --exec /usr/sbin/wpa_supplicant -- -B -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlp3s0
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
+ eend 0 'Failed to start WPA Supplicant Daemon'                                                                                                 [ ok ]
+ service_set_value command /usr/sbin/wpa_supplicant
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ return 0
++ command -v start_post
+ '[' '' = start_post ']'
++ command -v cgroup_cleanup
+ '[' cgroup_cleanup = cgroup_cleanup ']'
+ '[' start = stop ']'
++ command -v cgroup2_remove
+ '[' cgroup2_remove = cgroup2_remove ']'
+ '[' start = stop ']'
+ '[' -z /usr/sbin/wpa_supplicant ']'
+ shift
+ continue 2
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ exit 0
```

`mesh_fwding=1` is added by wpa_cli save_config, I tried without this line as well.

In `wpa_cli` I see `CTRL-EVENT-NETWORK-NOT-FOUND`.

In `scan_result` for my working phone I see
`[WPA2-PSK-CCMP][ESS]    POCO X3 Pro`

for router
`[WPA-PSK-CCMP+TKIP][WPA2-?][ESS]        271`.

I tried log level DEBUG but no additional information in `wpa_cli`.

In `dmesg` I see output only for the smartphone - but nothing when tethering is disabled.

I rent this appartment and my landlord does not know the password for the wi-fi router so I cannot see the settings. The model of router is **Huawei EchoLife HG8245H5**.

Currently I am in Georgia country and I tried to add
country="GE"
and `/etc/init.d/wpa_supplicant restart`.

In `lspci` I have `Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] (rev 34)`. Maybe wi-fi card on the laptop is too old?

Please help :(

Comment: Did you ask the Landlord how you can connect?

Comment: @John The landlord said the Wi-Fi password and it works on my Android.

Comment: I think debug log level usually goes to syslog, are there any new messages in there? (What if you run wpa_supplicant with `-d -d -d`?) Are there any messages from `iw event` while trying to connect? Is this an WPA-TKIP network? Is this a mixed mode WPA/WPA2 network? Apparently wpa_supplicant removed TKIP support recently *and* has a bug where it refuses to connect to mixed mode networks despite those supporting WPA2 just fine.

Comment: @user1686 `Is this an WPA-TKIP network?` how can I check it?

Comment: @user1686 added output with `-d -d -d`

Comment: In `iw wlan0 scan`, under the SSID, you'll see an `WPA:` section for WPA1 and/or an `RSN:` section for WPA2. (If the network doesn't support WPA1, for example, it won't have an "WPA:" section.) Each of those sections will list ciphers `TKIP` for the legacy WPA1 cipher and/or `CCMP` for the standard WPA2 AES cipher.

Answer (score 1):

Emerge with [USE](https://packages.gentoo.org/packages/net-wireless/wpa_supplicant) `tkip`.

Thanks [@user1686](https://superuser.com/users/1686/user1686) for the tip.